# Rails how to create two models that have a has_one dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models the account model depends on the id of the user model. I need them to be saved in the same transaction and if the validation on one of them fails then the transaction should fail. The problem is that the user model is getting saved even if the account model is invalid. What is that I'm doing wrong ?

Also why is rails open another transaction after saving ?

And here is the code :

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  username        :string(255)
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  active          :boolean
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  has_one :account, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end



# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: accounts
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  first_name      :string(255)
#  last_name       :string(255)
#  user_id         :integer
#  account_type_id :integer
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, if: Proc.new { |record| record.is_customer? }
  validates_presence_of :name, if: Proc.new { |record| record.is_business? }

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :account_type_id

  def is_customer?
    self.account_type_id == 1
  end

  def is_business?
    self.account_type_id == 2
  end

  def define_business
    self.account_type_id = 2
  end
end




def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  @user.create_account business_params

  @user.account.define_business

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save && @account.save
      set_current_account @user

      format.html { redirect_to business_dashboard_path }
      format.json { head :created, location: business_dashboard_path }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: { errors: @account.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Console output:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "password_digest", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 21 Mar 2014 21:10:15 UTC +00:00], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$93pKlgadnoetCpBCdSSRtenLDbWnribprhLVX.gZ6i35WcsI6UuRi"], ["updated_at", Fri, 21 Mar 2014 21:10:15 UTC +00:00], ["username", "business12@email.com"]]
(7.2ms)  commit transaction
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: What exactly is the code you're executing?

Comment: The create method is from controller. That method is executed.

Comment: I don't understand. In your question, you keep talking about adding two models in 1 transaction. I don't see a callback (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) in your model (which are executed in a transaction), nor do I see any transaction code that you wrote. Transactions don't appear magically out of nowhere. Please provide the code you're using to create the models, and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: until now I've been using user.save && account.save this saves both models in a transaction if both of them are valid but if the account model fails validation then only the first one is saved.

Comment: There is no need for me to open new a transaction is opened by rails

Comment: Yes, but you want 2 statements in a single transaction.

Comment: Yes and I want to know why are there linked together if both are valid ? Also how I can make so that when I create the account or user entity the other entity is created and if one of them fails validation then neither of them is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Rails wraps model operations in a transaction by default. If you execute:

```
@user.save && @account.save
```

you get two transactions, one for each call of the method `save`. If the first DB operation succeeds, the second is executed.

With this code, three things can possibly happen:

1. `@user` is invalid, so `@user.save` fails and returns `false` in which case no record is created in the DB.
2. `@user` is valid, so `@user.save` succeeds and returns `true`, but `@account` is invalid, so `@account.save` fails in which case 1 (user) record is created in the DB.
3. `@user` is valid, so `@user.save` succeeds and returns `true`, and `@account` is valid as well in which case both records are created in the DB.

You want to eliminate #2. **You cannot use `@user.save && @account.save` in your case.** It does not execute both DB operations in one transaction.

Let me start by saying that in order to save two models in a single transaction, you have two options:

## 1. Use an explicit transaction

You could explicitly do both in a [transaction](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods) like so:

```
User.transaction do
  @user.save!
  @account.save!
end
```

Note that bang methods are used here (`save!`, not `save`) because they raise exceptions in case of an invalid model which triggers a roll-back of the transaction.

This way, you end up with either 0 or 2 records in your DB. You could implement this as a convenience method in one of your models or in your controller.

## 2. Use callbacks

You could also use [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). This can only be done in a model, like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  has_one :account, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  after_create :create_account

  private

  def create_account
    # do something
  end
end
```

This triggers a method `create_account` in your user model (consider making it private) which is executed after the user is successfully created in the DB.

Given that your user model might not have all the relevant information it needs to create the account, option #1 (i.e. `Account.transaction do`) **seems like the better fit for you.**

Comment: There should be an easy way like there is with the has_many association,  rails detects all the entities added and creates them on save. I don't create any transaction or anything in that case.

Comment: After thinking about it, I now understand your problem much better than before. I've added another answer including a test case.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using `autosave: true` which is correct but unfortunately you're using `.create_account` instead of `build_account`. The [has_one Association Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) explains:

> The build_association method returns a new object of the associated type.
>   This object will be instantiated from the passed attributes,
>   and the link through its foreign key will be set,
>   but the associated object will not yet be saved.

Since you're using `autosave: true` on the User association, you could build (not create) the account and **then only save the user,** which then saves the associated account as well. The benefit of using this is you don't need to worry about transactions at all.

I've [prepared a gist](https://gist.github.com/awendt/9842536) to demonstrate the difference between your code and mine. You can download both files and run them like so:

```
ruby what_you_have.rb
ruby what_you_need.rb
```

You'll notice the tests will fail on `what_you_have.rb` and pass on `what_you_need.rb`.

When using `create_account` and `user.save && account.save`, the tests always fail with an invalid user and a valid account. Why is that? Because with `user.create_account`, you've already saved a valid account in your database before attempting to save the user.

When using `build_account` and then only `user.save`, you tell ActiveRecord to save the user (given it's valid) and save the account along the way. If one of them is invalid, `user.save` does not save anything.